# Creating view content link that links to data based on taxonomy terms

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

how can I create view content link that links to data based on taxonomy terms?

I have stores in stores page...stores are in views..each store should have a link that links to its products.

Comment: you need to explain better, but I guess you want something like a breadcrumb?

Comment: No ...I have a page that have stores ( carrefour,pull&bear,nike,adidas..etc)
these stores should have links ..each store should have a link ..the link should take the user to the store products

Comment: make a views of your taxonomy, just simply showing the parent term for your stores page, once you created that view, once a person click on a taxonomy term, it will load the content related to that term, nothing fancy needed.

Comment: can you make it clearer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to achieve this:

- Add relationship that references the taxonomy field you use in the content type.
- Add a `Taxonomy term: Term ID` field in Views. Exclude it from output.
- Add a `Custom Text` field in Views.
- Under `Rewrite Results` check the `Output this field as a link` checkbox. In the link path use the token for taxonomy term id - `[tid]`. If you want to use the core page, just enter `taxonomy/term/[tid]`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sure, glad it helped!

Comment: Wait there is a problem hehehe Im sorry but its taking me to "Page not found" ../taxonomy/term/%5Btid%5D

Comment: You need to make sure that the taxonomy term ID field is listed *before* the custom text, otherwise Views won't replace the value. Does `[tid]` appear in the `Replacement Patterns` for custom text field?

Comment: it doesn't appear

Comment: Then make sure that the `[tid]` is before the custom link field; you can reorder the fields by clicking on the `Rearrange` local task in views.

Comment: it works now but its taking me to ../taxonomy/term/0

Comment: You didn't configure something correctly. Export the view and update the original question.

Comment: I didnt fix the taxonomy , now it works thanks alot :)

Comment: can I ask 1 last question ?? how can I make the HTML Construction of the inner items? the terms items

Comment: Not sure I understand it completely; include more descriptions and post as a separate question so others can have a look as well.